# crash when assigning function to function pointer

Tags: ios, objective-c, pointers, function-pointers

I have a very strange crash . Please see code below.

```
typedef void(*testFunc)();
testFunc func[2];
-(void) get_testfunc : (NSInteger)testId
{

   NSInteger testId = [_picker selectedRowInComponent:0];
    NSLog(@"test id = %d",testId);
    switch(testId){
        case 0:
            aes_tests_init();
            func[0] = aes_tests_init;
            func[1] = aes_tests_init;  <<--crashes in this assignment
            NSLog(@" 0%p 0%p 0%p",func[0],func[1],aes_tests_init);
            break;
        case 1:
            aes_tests_init();
            func[0] = aes_tests_init;
            func[1] = aes_tests_init;
            NSLog(@" 0%p 0%p 0%p",func[0],func[1],aes_tests_init);
            break;
        case 2:
            aes_tests_init();
            func[0] = aes_tests_init;
            func[1] = aes_tests_init;
            NSLog(@" 0%p 0%p 0%p",func[0],func[1],aes_tests_init);
            break;
        default:
        NSLog(@"invalid enc type %d",testId);
        break;
}
return;
}
```

I have a picker from which i get the input testID . I use this func pointers in the caller func (on button press) and print the results . i have 6 cases and all my switch cases execute successfully and give proper results but the first case. 
crash indicated by Xcode moves to next line  after commenting the above indicated line!

aes_tests_init is a method in an included static library.For simplicity i made all ptrs to as_tests_init.
Whats wrong here ?Please somebody suggest.

Comment: this is not C. remove the C tag please.

Comment: This could be an issue with Function pointers which is common in C / objective -c .

Comment: and which one of those two are you using?

Comment: I m using function pointers in objective-c , that does not limit logic of function pointers to objective -c  i guess.

Comment: yes, but the small snippet of code you posted also has other features that are definitely not shared with plain old C.

Comment: I don't see any reason for the code to crash there.  Can you post the stacktrace please?

Answer (score 0):

Ah, crash stopped after i copy pasted the other case's code to case 0 . Don't still know what was the real reason for cause, all cases looked same . At least i was able to proceed. Sorry for the trouble guys . Thank you.